# PHP How to perform an http request passing cookies and save result to a string

Tags: php, http, cookies, session-cookies

I would like to perform an http request and pass all cookies received by the current script (in particular session identifying cookies) to this request. Then I would like to save the result in a string for further manipulation. What is the best way to do this in PHP ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Send cookie with file_get_contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431160/php-send-cookie-with-file-get-contents)

Comment: possiblr duplicate of [Copying cookies from first response to next request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212442/copying-cookies-from-first-response-to-next-request)

Comment: Gordon - one more such example and you may convince me to close this question ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cURL ? - it is simple and supprot cookies .

Edit 19.1 - Here is example

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR is file where cURL put cookies sent from server and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE is file with cookies for sending by cURL ( setting it to same one will make it cookies file ).

Another option is manually read cookies from result ( set CURLOPT_HEADER to '1' - it will put result header into $output ) and send cookies via CURLOPT_COOKIE ( set it to list of cookies in format 'foo=bar;bar=foo;' )

Note - libcurl must be enabled in php.ini

Comment: Could you provide some sourcecode here that passes cookies and parametrs of the currenct script and is this library available on a standard PHP hosting?

Comment: Thanks- looks good, btw- is it possible to do this without libcurl?

Comment: It is not working for ASP.NET session cookies. cURL is not capturing them.

Comment: @Volatil3 can you check if cookies are really sent (using CURLOPT_HEADER) ? As they may be not sent or they may be HTTPS only for example